# Values of an array changing randomly during execution 

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to make a little programme in C using SDL, displaying a robot moving on a grid. This grid is represented by a txt file of 0s and 1s.

Here is the fonction creating an array from the txt file, which works.

```
// create a map(array) from a text file
int (*newMap())[SIZE_HEIGHT][SIZE_WIDTH]
{
static const char filename[] = "input.txt";  /* the name of a file to open */
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");  /* try to open the file */
int map[SIZE_HEIGHT][SIZE_WIDTH];

char line[BUFSIZ]; /* space to read a line into */
int k = 0;
while ( fgets(line, sizeof line, file)!=NULL && k<SIZE_HEIGHT) /* read each line */
{
    int i;
    char *token = line; /* point to the beginning of the line */

    for ( i = 0; i<SIZE_WIDTH; i++ )
    {
        map[k][i]=((int)*token)-48;
        token+=sizeof(char);
        printf("map[%d][%d]=%d\n", (int)k,(int)i,map[k][i]);
    }
    puts("----\n");
    k++;
}
fclose(file);

int (*p)[SIZE_HEIGHT][SIZE_WIDTH];
p=&map;
return p;
```

}

Then I try to put the grid on the sreen (not the whole fonction):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Parameters.h"
#include "simulation.h"
#include "editor.h"

void simulate(SDL_Surface *ecran)
{
SDL_Surface *carreVert = SDL_LoadBMP("carreVert.bmp");
SDL_Surface *carreRouge = SDL_LoadBMP("carreRouge.bmp");
SDL_Surface *robot = SDL_LoadBMP("robotRouge.bmp");

SDL_SetColorKey(robot, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, SDL_MapRGB(robot->format, 255, 255, 255));

int (*map)[SIZE_HEIGHT][SIZE_WIDTH];
 map=newMap();
SDL_Rect positionFond;

int i;
int j;

for(j=0; j<SIZE_HEIGHT; j++)
{
    for(i=0; i<SIZE_WIDTH; i++)

    {


        positionFond.x = 100*i;
        positionFond.y = 100*j;
        if((*map)[j][i]+1)
        {

            SDL_BlitSurface(carreVert, NULL, ecran, &positionFond);
        }else
        {


            SDL_BlitSurface(carreRouge, NULL, ecran, &positionFond);
        }

    }

}
```

And then  something strange happens: when I observe the array *map with the debugger, I see that the values are changing when I go through the test. So the grid does appear, but not with the right pattern. Why does that happen?

Edit:no error an compiler.

Edit: Any guess of what might do that would be gladly accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `map` is local to the function. It ceases to exist when the function finishes. You pass its address to the caller, but when the caller tries to use it ... **BANG!**

Fast solution: make the array `map` a `static` one: **make sure you never call `newMap` more than once per run**.

Other solutions:

- move the creation of the array outwards and pass the address around
- use `malloc` and friends to manage the array

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to an object with automatic storage duration (an array that gets "deallocated" on return from the function where it is declared), so you end up seeing random garbage.